# Sending JMeter CSV results to InfluxDB using Logparser Input Plugin

Tags: jmeter, influxdb, grok, telegraf

In order to have JMeter live results into

I'm trying to parse JMeter CSV result file that has following columns:

> timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,success,failureMessage,bytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,myCustomVariableMetric

I'm using this telegraf plugin :

- https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/logparser

But I am not able to parse this data:

> 1526659742584,60151,XXXX-us-west-2b-300000,200,"Xxxxxxx",TG-172.31.17.55 1-7,true,,4036727,341,341,http://www.example.com,1047,0,151

I don't know what is the pattern for:

- 1526659742584 => It's a timestamp in Java
- XXXX-us-west-2b-300000 => WORD is not working due to '-'
- TG-172.31.17.55 1-7 => Same as above and also due to '.'
- http://www.example.com

I tried this :

- https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution but not sure it's the most performing:

> %{INT:timestamp},%{INT:elapsed},%{USERNAME:label},%{WORD:rc},"%{GREEDYDATA:rMsg}",%{GREEDYDATA:threadName},%{WORD:success},%{GREEDYDATA:fMsg},%{INT:bytes},%{INT:grpThreads},%{INT:allThreads},%{GREEDYDATA:url},%{INT:Latency},%{INT:IdleTime},%{INT:myCustomVariableMetric}

Please comment or answer if there is a better one.